# How to read FoxPro Memory Variable Files (.MEM) with Delphi

Tags: delphi, variables, foxpro

I'm trying to read a [.MEM file](http://1drv.ms/1R5l9Fy) using Delphi. It's a FoxPro Memory Variable Files. I've tried to read using TFileStream and load into TStringList. But, it only returns the first word.

```
F := TFileStream.Create(sFile, fmOpenRead);
L := TStringList.Create;
try
  F.Position := 0;
  L.LoadFromStream(F);
  ShowMessage(L.Text);
finally
  F.Free;
  L.Free;
end;
```

The reason is because I want to migrate some useful .MEM values from an old program to my new program. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code assumes that a .mem file is text, which it is not. It's a binary format file. They're similar to the Clipper .mem file format; you can find that format [here](http://www.zelczak.com/clipp_en.htm), which may be enough to get you started on the right path.

Comment: Reading files is easy enough. How do you propose to parse the file though?

Comment: Although a string list is wrong for binary data, do note that you can use LoadFromFile and so avoid creating a stream object. Also note that TFile.ReadAllText avoids the need for a string list.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a one-time affair and you have access to a VFP installation - i.e. the IDE, not only the runtime - then David Heffernan's suggestion is certainly the most sensible way. In this case you can load and inspect the .MEM via

```
release all extended && to clear away all existing memvars
restore from foo     && assuming the file in question is named FOO.MEM
activate window Locals  && inspect the variables...
list memory to foo      && or list them to FOO.TXT
modify file foo.txt
```

However, `LIST MEMORY` (and `DISPLAY MEMORY`) also include all the system variables - the things that start with an underscore - which would need to be parsed off.

If it's an ongoing affair - repeated imports necessary - and you know which variables you need then there are two fairly clean and easy ways.

The first is only valid if a VFP IDE is installed on the computer on which the Delphi program is to be run. In this case you can instantiate VFP from Delphi (leave it invisible), have it read the .MEM and then query individual variables:

```
procedure fetch_variables_from_MEM (mem_filename: string; var_list: CFoos);
var
   fox: Variant;
   foo: CFoo;
begin
   fox := CreateOleObject('VisualFoxpro.Application.9');
   try
      fox.DoCmd('release all extended');
      fox.DoCmd('restore from ' + mem_filename);
      for foo in var_list do
         foo.Value := fox.Eval('m.' + foo.Name);
   finally
      fox.Quit;  // AutoQuit not supported
   end;
end;
```

I glossed over some details, like that `CoInitialize()` needs to be called on the thread somewhere before calling this, and I assumed suitable definitions for the variable list (a list/collection of hypothetical CFoo objects), but the sketched outline works - even in 64-bit Delphi.

The advantage is that things like datetime values arrive as TDateTime by virtue of the COM infrastructure and the use of variants.

The second easy way is applicable if an IDE is not available on the machine where the Delphi program is to be used but you have access to an IDE somewhere, so that you can build a small COM server:

```
define class FoxWrapper as custom olepublic
   function Eval (cExpression as string) as variant
      return evaluate(m.cExpression)
   procedure DoCmd (cCommand as string)
      &cCommand
enddefine
```

This can then be used instead of "VisualFoxPro.Application.9" in the example above. Note: for 64-bit Delphi you need to build this as an out-of-process server (i.e. an EXE). Also, this may run afoul of the VFP licence conditions.

For accessing the data directly, here's some quick & dirty Delphi code that I modelled after some FoxPro stuff that I coded eons ago and updated for VFP9. This is proof-of-principle code with simplified array handling and other compromises for the sake of exposition; it lacks all the production-quality noise necessitated by Delphi's half-assed language definition and its quarter-assed runtime.

```
type
   TMEMVarHeader = packed record
      var_name: array [0..10] of AnsiChar;
      mem_type: AnsiChar;               // 0ACDHLNOQYacdhlnoqy
      big_size: UInt32;                 // only if mem_type == 'H'
      width   : Byte;                   // special meaning if mem_type == 'H'
      decimals: Byte;
      padding : array [0..13] of Byte;  // 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0
   end;

   SizeOf_TMEMVarHeader_eq_32 = true .. SizeOf(TMEMVarHeader) = 32;

   TMEMVarInfo = record
      header: TMEMVarHeader;
      null_t: AnsiChar;
      name  : AnsiString;
      value : Variant;
      function ReadFromStream (stream: TStream): Boolean;  // false if EOF
   end;

function TMEMVarInfo.ReadFromStream (stream: TStream): Boolean;
const
   DELPHI_EPOCH = 2415019.0;
var
   header_bytes_read: Integer;
   name_length: UInt16;
   text_length: UInt32;
   array_dim_1: UInt16;
   array_dim_2: UInt16;
   d: TDate;          // 64-bit double
   l: Boolean;
   n: Double;         // 64-bit double
   q: array of Byte;
   c: AnsiString;
   t: TDateTime;      // 64-bit double
   y: Int64;
   binary: Boolean;
   i: Cardinal;
   a: array of Variant;
   v: TMEMVarInfo;
begin
   name := '';  value := Unassigned;
   header_bytes_read := stream.Read(header, SizeOf(header));
   if header_bytes_read <> Sizeof(header) then begin
      if not ((header_bytes_read = 1) and (header.var_name[0] = #26)) then
         raise Exception.Create('unexpected MEM file format (problem reading header)');
      result := false;  // EOF
      EXIT;
   end;
   result := true;
   // variable name
   if header.var_name[0] = #0 then begin  // long variable name
      assert(header.mem_type = LoCase(header.mem_type));
      stream.ReadBuffer(name_length, Sizeof(name_length));
      SetLength(name, name_length);
      stream.ReadBuffer(name[1], name_length);
   end else begin
      assert(header.mem_type = UpCase(header.mem_type));
      name := header.var_name;
   end;
   // variable value
   case UpCase(header.mem_type) of
      'A':
         begin
            stream.ReadBuffer(array_dim_1, SizeOf(array_dim_1));
            stream.ReadBuffer(array_dim_2, SizeOf(array_dim_2));
            if array_dim_2 = 0 then // it's a vector, not an array
               array_dim_2 := 1;
            SetLength(a, array_dim_1 * array_dim_2);
            for i := 0 to array_dim_1 * array_dim_2 - 1 do begin
               if not v.ReadFromStream(stream) then
                  raise Exception.Create('error reading array element');
               a[i] := v.value;
            end;
            value := a;
         end;
      '0':  begin  stream.ReadBuffer(null_t, 1);  value := Null;  end;
      'C', 'H', 'Q':
         begin
            if UpCase(header.mem_type) = 'H' then begin // length > 254
               binary := header.width <> 0;
               text_length := header.big_size;
            end else begin
               binary := UpCase(header.mem_type) = 'Q';
               text_length := header.width;
            end;
            if binary then begin
               SetLength(q, text_length);  stream.ReadBuffer(q[0], text_length);  value := q;
            end else begin
               SetLength(c, text_length);  stream.ReadBuffer(c[1], text_length);  value := c;
            end;
         end;
      'D':  begin  stream.ReadBuffer(d, Sizeof(d));  if d > 0 then d := d - DELPHI_EPOCH;  VarCast(value, d, varDate);  end;
      'L':  begin  stream.ReadBuffer(l, Sizeof(l));  value := l;  end;
      'N':  begin  stream.ReadBuffer(n, Sizeof(n));  value := n;  end;
      'T':  begin  stream.ReadBuffer(t, Sizeof(t));  if t > 0 then t := t - DELPHI_EPOCH;  value := t;  end;
      'Y':  begin  stream.ReadBuffer(y, Sizeof(y));  VarCast(value, y / 10000.0, varCurrency);  end;
   else
      raise Exception.Create('unexpected type ''' + header.mem_type + ''' in MEM file');
   end;
end;
```

For reading a .MEM, create a `TFileStream` and a `TMEMVarInfo` variable, then read variables one by one until `var_info.ReadFromStream(stream)` returns `false`.

Note: the byte at offset 19h (shown as 3 in the structure comment) is a code page identifier. The values are the same as [those found in .DBF headers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/8t45x02s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), i.e. 1 for DOS 437, 3 for Windows 1252 and so on. However, even though VFP stores these identifiers when writing a .MEM, all the newer versions of VFP that I tested **completely ignore these code page marks** when loading a .MEM. A self-written importer could put the code page marks to good use, though.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the binary .mem files is not the correct way to proceed. The correct solution is to get VFP to export the data. It knows how to read it. Get VFP to export to a known format, and read that. This is the standard approach to data migration.

Comment: You're assuming that the OP has access to an appropriate Fox version (IDE) which is not necessarily given. MEM files were especially popular pre-VFP (e.g. FPD, FPW) while with VFP there's often nary a MEM in sight, apart from the EUROPEAN.MEM which ships with VFP.

Comment: @Darth That's a reasonable assumption.

Comment: No, it isn't. Apart from that: VFP (**any** VFP) can read the test file all right with a simple `REST FROM test`, which is certainly the fastest way of inspecting it. However, dumping the contents of the .MEM in a format importable by Delphi is a different matter, especially with doubles and datetime stamps (which are bound to lose precision when being converted to text). Fox has no means of enumerating memory variables other than parsing the output of `DISP MEMO` or `LIST MEMO`; variable names need to be extracted from that, sysvars removed, values queried and converted.

Comment: @Darth That all sounds like routine data migration fare to me.

Comment: Migration is a one-time affair, and such a context would make your suggestion certainly the cleanest and most straightforward (although Foxen would only be available if it's an in-house affair, not a bought program/system). The picture changes if the Delphi program is to run for some time alongside the old programs until everything's been migrated. Even the moral equivalent of `createobject("VisualFoxPro.Application")` - which works like a charm with Delphi's late binding - requires a VFP IDE licence. Making a COM wrapper for `.DoCmd()` is borderline illegal, as is loading the naked runtime.

Comment: This answer does not address the question asked - how to read MEM files without VFP.